# Problems with RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I have some problems with RSACryptoServiceProvider on my machine. If a create a new instance:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
```

I already get an exception, under CspKeyContainerInfo property :

- Exportable  'rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'   bool {System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException}
- base    {"Key does not exist.\r\n"} System.SystemException {System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException}

If I try the same code on the another PC, everything works fine. Are there some settings on my PC that I can check to see if both of them are configured properly and in what the configuration defers? Any clue on what may be the problem?

Thanks

EDIT:
It seem's that it only happens on framework 4.0. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work.

```
            CspParameters parms = new CspParameters();
            parms.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoFlags;
            parms.KeyContainerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
            parms.ProviderType = ((Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5) || ((Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5) && (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1))) ? 0x18 : 1;

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parms);
```

I do not know why, but it is just like that.
If anyone know why of this behavior, and comment is more then welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Setting the KeyContainerName to a NewGuid did the trick for me. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the provider type in the windows registry:
\local_machine\software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider\

Look for the provider you want and check the Type value...